# ad whirl add - admob not service

Tags: iphone, xcode4, admob, adwhirl

adwhirl(iad, admob, houseAd) add to xcode4

deviece test...

iad : ok see service

houseAd : ok see service

but...

admob : not see!!!

log code

```
2011-10-19 13:38:07.739 KingKatWorldFree[948:707] <Google> Invalid Request: {
    errors = "Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?";
    "google.afma.notify_dt" = 1318999087687;
    "request_id" = undefined;
    type = unknown;
}
```

Why admob not See????

plese help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you configured AdMob on the AdWhirl backend with your AdMob publisher ID, check to make sure there is no whitespace before or after your ID.  Otherwise AdMob will not recognize your publisher ID.